# data filter not work when use paste in input text in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

I am developing a web app using angular framework and angularfire2. My problem is my data filter is not working when i paste a copied text. But it works well when i type the text. How do i fix this problem?

Below is list.html

```
<th colspan="5">
  Search Serial Number/Model: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchstring" 
  (input)="searchuser($event)" />
</th>
```

Below is the function in list.ts

```
searchuser(searchbar) {
  this.filteredusers = this.temparr;
  var q = searchbar.target.value;
  if (q.trim() == '') {
    return;
  }
  this.filteredusers = this.filteredusers.filter((v) => {
    if (v.serialnumber && v.serialnumber.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) > 
        -1 ||
        v.detailspecification && 
        v.detailspecification.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1  ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
}
```

Comment: Try  `(paste)="searchuser($event)"`

Comment: I was trying your code and I can paste without issues... what navigator are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngChange event in form for detect every change in your input so you don't need to use another function for paste .

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dataSource.comments" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

you can use change instead of ngModelChange to.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use paste event.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchstring"  (input)="searchuser($event)" (paste)="searchuser($event)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ngModelChange` to detect every changes on input fields

Replace `(input)="searchuser($event)"` to `(ngModelChange)="searchuser($event)"`

Try this

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchstring" (ngModelChange)="searchuser($event)" />
```